# Bitbake fails on compiling gcc-cross

Tags: openembedded, bitbake

i am trying to compile gcc-cross with bitbake(openembedded classic, bitbake), but it fails on desktop-file-utils and accordingly on desktop-file-utils-native-0.16. Have installed libglib, and pkg-config shows me glib-2.0 as available.(Ubuntu 12.04, 64Bit)

```
pkg-config --modversion glib-2.0
2.32.4

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION        = "1.13.3"
METADATA_BRANCH   = "master"
METADATA_REVISION = "5d95b1c"
TARGET_ARCH       = "arm"
TARGET_OS         = "linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE           = "beagleboard"
DISTRO            = "angstrom"
DISTRO_VERSION    = "v2014.01"
TARGET_FPU        = "hard"
```

Someone any idea which dependecies i missing ?
(no solution to update bitbake and openembedded to newest version)

```
/home/user/development/oe/tmp/work/i686-linux/desktop-file-utils-native-0.16-r0/desktop-file-utils-0.16/configure: line 11285: syntax error near unexpected token `DESKTOP_FILE_UTILS,'
/home/user/development/oe/tmp/work/i686-linux/desktop-file-utils-native-0.16-r0/desktop-file-utils-0.16/configure: line 11285: `PKG_CHECK_MODULES(DESKTOP_FILE_UTILS, glib-2.0 >= 2.8.0)'
NOTE: package desktop-file-utils-native-0.16-r0: task do_configure: Failed
ERROR: Task 68 (virtual:native:/home/user/development/oe/openembedded/recipes/desktop-file-utils/desktop-file-utils_0.16.bb, do_configure) failed with exit code '1'
ERROR: 'virtual:native:/home/user/development/oe/openembedded/recipes/desktop-file-utils/desktop-file-utils_0.16.bb' failed
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`pkg-config` shows you the version number of your host-system and not of your target system.

You target-system has a glib-2.0 (http://git.openembedded.org/openembedded/tree/recipes/glib-2.0?h=master&id=5d95b1c603279f6b9d519865d338fc8c6dd6efb4). But it seems to me that Angstrom needs a newer version of glib.

You have more luck to use a angstrom from year 2011.

Answer (score 0):

So, i found the solution.
there was no glib-2.0 installed on the build machine.
So you must compile gettext-native, pkgconfig-native, glib-2.0-native
(pkg-config and glib have circular dependency).
After these steps all files are compiled well